# How to point to correct path to database of application installed using clickone

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce, localdb

I Developed a windows form application with database and published

when i tryed to get backup of database which i implemented using the code

```
 string database = GetDataDirectory();
        MessageBox.Show(database);
 SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();

        using (SqlConnection backupConn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            backupConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\BbCon.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;";
            backupConn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand backupcomm = new SqlCommand())
            {
                backupcomm.Connection = backupConn;
                backupcomm.CommandText = @"BACKUP DATABASE @DBNAME TO DISK='c:\\Users\Public\\BbCon.bak'";
                backupcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DBNAME", database+"\\BbCon.mdf");
                int x =  backupcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if(x == -1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("DataBase Backup Created Successfully at c:\\Users\\Public");
                }
            }
            backupConn.Close();
        }

private string  GetDataDirectory()
    {
        ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
        return ad.DataDirectory;
        //return Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString();
    }
```

i am getting an error [image]

but when i navigated to the directory which shown in the error message i found a the Bbcon.mdf file but i am getting the error

please please help me with this problem i am stucked with problem please please help me

Answer (score 1):

You cannot backup a database by it's physical filename(s).  You must backup a database by its database name:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [BbCon] TO DISK = 'c:\Users\Public\BbCon.bak'
```